# I need to select clients who have multiple records in one column

Tags: sql

I'm tasked with selecting all clients who have traveled in 2017 and 2018, but not 2019.

I've tried something like the below but it doesn't work. I'm pretty much a novice at SQL, VBA is more my thing.

I could say where tour date is less than 2019-01-01, but this may only result in customers that have booked once for a tour before 2019, I need to select people that are traveling at least once in 2017 and then at least once in 2018, but not in 2019.

```
select clientid from cust

    where tour_date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31'
    and tour_date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31'
    and tour_date < '2019-01-01'
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use correlated subquery with exists and not exists

```
select clientid from cust a
where exist
  (select 1 from cust b where a.clientid=b.clientid and tour_date  between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31')
and exist 
  (select 1 from cust b where a.clientid=b.clientid and tour_date  between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31')
and not exists
   (select 1 from cust b where a.clientid=b.clientid and tour_date  between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31')
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also try using aggregation here:

```
SELECT clientid
FROM cust
GROUP BY clientid
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN tour_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
    COUNT(CASE WHEN tour_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
    COUNT(CASE WHEN tour_date < '2019-01-01' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Comment: This one works really nicely, thanks - Is there any way to add more columns to the query? Thanks. For example, each line in cust has the clientid, their booking reference, the code of the product etc. I'd like to see the clientid in one column and the product code in the next column "left(tourno,1) as Tourno" EDIT: nevermind, sorted it. Ta!

Comment: That's a bit of an open-ended question, because once we have aggregated by `clientid`, it is no longer clear _which_ value we should take for the booking reference, code, etc.  If you really need this follow up, then you should add some sample data to your question.

Comment: Sure, I understand. If I do this: "SELECT clientid, left(tourno,1) as Tourno
FROM cust
GROUP BY clientid, tourno
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN tour_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
    COUNT(CASE WHEN tour_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
    COUNT(CASE WHEN tour_date < '2019-01-01' THEN 1 END) > 0;"  Then I get one line for each client ID and each Tourno, so a clientid can appear 3 times with 3 separate clientid's, or just once which means they bought a "E" product multiple times. Problem is I can't add a tour_date to this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
SELECT clientid
FROM
(
    SELECT clientid,YEAR(tour_date) YR
    FROM cust
    WHERE YEAR(tour_date) IN (2017,2018)
)A
GROUP BY clientid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT YR) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want clients and not the details of their trips, then use aggregation.  I would phrase this as:

```
SELECT clientid
FROM cust
GROUP BY clientid
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN tour_date >= '2017-01-01' AND tour_date < '2018-01-01' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN tour_date >= '2018-01-01' AND tour_date < '2019-01-01' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN tour_date >= '2019-01-01' AND tour_date < '2020-01-01' THEN 1 END) = 0 ;
```

Each condition in the `HAVING` clause is counting the number of tours during the year in question.  The comparison `> 0` says there is at least one; the `= 0` says there are none during that year.